# Magento 2 - display custom product attribute instead of the price in minicart

Tags: magento2, product, price, knockoutjs, mini-cart

I try to display a custom product attribute instead of the price in minicart.

I saw that the html file that I have to override is price.html from module_checkout. price.html :

```
<!-- ko ifnot: true -->
     <div class="price-container">
         <span class="price-wrapper" data-bind="html: price"></span>
     </div>
<!-- /ko --> 
<!-- ko if: true -->
     custom attribute product value here
<!-- /ko -->
```

And I already override this html in a requirejs-config.js :

```
var config = {
//override price.html file
  map: {
    '*' : {
      'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/price.html' : 'Vendor_Module/template/minicart/item/price.html'
    }
  }
};
```

I tried to put in that file a knockoutjs code if and ifnot, but I don't know how to retrieve my own product value in this html file. If someone know ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Hope you doing well.

Please clean/flush cache and deploy magento.

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy (add " -f " if it's in
>   Developer mode

if condition not needed.

```
<!-- ko if: true -->

<!-- /ko -->
```

**price.html is called from here.**

> /magento_directory/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

```
<!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
     <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} -->
     <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

**Price renderer  is added using xml.**

> checkout_cart_sidebar_item_price_renderers.xml

**so please first clear cache & Deploy.**

**Thanks**